# What does WEB-INF stand for in a Java EE web application?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, web-applications, web-inf

Most of the places on the internet say it stands for **WEB INF**ormation.

I rather doubt it. The folder contains executables. **Information** is not a suitable name for it.

Comment: META-INF/services/ essentially contains code, if in a rather minimalist, specialist language.

Comment: Duplicate question which was asked in a much better way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-ee-web-application

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As far as I know, "INF" stands for "Information", as you said.  It probably was named `WEB-INF` for similarity with the `META-INF` directory in JAR files.  Sometimes the meaning of a directory changes so much over time that it no longer makes sense.  For example, `bin` directories in Unix/Linux often contain non-binary "executable" files, such as shell scripts.

Comment: What's wrong with sticking with `META-INF` then? Why invent `WEB-INF` when `META-INF` already serves the needed purpose?

Comment: @Pacerier: Separation of concerns. `WEB-INF` is accessible as web resource. I.e. `ServletContext#getResource()/getResourceAsStream()` can access it as well as `ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher()`. `META-INF` isn't accessible as web resource and shouldn't be. I.e. you shouldn't put web resources like JSP files there.

Answer (score 18):

I believe it's really named WEB-INF to mirror the META-INF directory in a jar file, which contains meta information. I do see what you mean about it being as much about executables as "information" but the main point is that it doesn't contain the documents of the application.

Comment: @jon skeet : change the tags if you wish

Comment: Looks like it's been done - will edit the answer now so it still makes sense :)

Comment: (Is there now any point in having this answer as well as Andy White's? I'm tempted to delete.)

Answer (score 11):

It's a directory to store private application content. Anything your app needs but your client doesn't can be stored there. Anything in that directory is not visible to the web.

Source:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/source.html#Directory_Structure
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs70/webapp/basics.html#136976

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of what `WEB-INF` actually stands for.

Answer (score 6):

I think, the only logical definition is WEB-INF is mirror of META-INF. Naming is really important for beginners and if it is confusing then the subject is getting harder to understand.

Answer (score 3):

The `WEB_INF` folder contains the `web.xml` (deployment descriptor) file, the classes, external libs etc and as `web.xml` file contains the information about the container urls, files etc, the folder is known as `WEB-INF`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of what `WEB-INF` actually stands for.

Comment: A better answer was added and accepted :) Quoting @andy-white `As far as I know, "INF" stands for "Information", as you said. It probably was named WEB-INF for similarity with the META-INF directory in JAR files.`