# images not appearing in jsp in netbeans

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, netbeans

I am working on a project in netbeans . I designed my webpage in dreamweaver, and copied the code in a jsp in my netbeans project. then I created an images folder under WEB-INF and stored the images used in my webpage . I also changed the path of my "img src" to that local path . But when I run it in my browser the images don't show up !

Please help ...

this is my package

|MyProj
  |WEB-INF
    |images
    |web.xml
  |home.jsp

here's my sample code:

`<td width="610"><div id="logom"><img src="WEB-INF/images/webDes.png" width="323" height="167" alt="logomain" /></div></td>`

Comment: is `WEB-INF/images/webDes.png` path correct relative to your current page???

Comment: yes it is . I have home.jsp under MyProj and my images under WEB-INF Which in turn is under MyProj .

Comment: is it showing the `alt` text that u have set?

Comment: yeah it is showing only that ...

Comment: Contents of the WEB-INF folder is not accessible to a browser. If you really want to place your images there, then you need to use a Servlet to serve them.

Comment: @That-Kickass-GirL : go to source code and click on the image link....if it doesnt open, then either you have permissions problem to the images folder or images is not there at all!!

Comment: Look at answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-web-application

Answer (score 0):

According to [JSR-000315](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-mrel-full-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-mrel-spec.pdf), page 121:

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named
>   "**WEB-INF**"...no other files contained in the **WEB-INF** directory may be
>   served directly to a client by the container.

and page 122:

> any requests to access the resources in **META-INF** directory must be
>   returned with a SC_NOT_FOUND(404) response.

Conclusion:
Normally you don't place your static resources such as CSS, HTML, JavaScript into either META-INF/ or WEB-INF/ especially when the project is **imported**(?) from Dreamweaver. Now I understand some might disagree w/ me on this coz there're actually ways (via JEE or framework) to archive that goal, and I have to admit that they are correct alrite. Although based on your background I assumed, I don't think you're incorporating JEE or any other framework on the project. So in your case, you might just wanna avoid using **WEB-INF/** (as well as **META-INF/**) directly.

Comment: I already posted this information in the comments above here.

Comment: @rickz: I realize you did, but I thought That-Kickass-GirL might find my answer a little bit easier to understand. If it is redundant, feel free to down vote or delete it. :)