# How to protect my jsp page from direct access

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am doing a web application using servlets and jsps. I had a index.html

Now i need to avoid direct access of my login page from browser

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Login App using Servlet and JSP</title>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="pink">
 <center>
 <a href="Register.jsp">Register</a>
 <a href="Login.jsp" >Login</a>
  </center>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to prevent direct access of Login.jsp from the browser

```
http://localhost:9090/LoginAppWithServletsJSPJDBC/Login.jsp
```

By googling I came to know that I need to use  `<security-constraint>` for this.

Please help me .How can I achieve this.

Comment: You must read more about security in general. I will recommend using spring and spring security for enforcing security. Read more about spring and spring security.

Comment: Are you using any other frameworks? spring? Stripes? Some more bare bones servlets?

Comment: @RaviH I am doing a basic login application using servlets and jsp.Now I am looking out for securing my jsp from direct access from browser. I am not using Spring for now.

Comment: This should be enough for now: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs70/webapp/security.html

Answer (score 3):

Simply move `Login.jsp` under `WEB-INF` that can't be accessed directly from the outside world.

Only application can access it whenever needed using `RequestDispatcher`.

Sample code:

```
// put this logic anywhere in your application whenever needed to show Login.jsp 
request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Please have a look at [What is WEB-INF used for in a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-web-application)