# How to restrict direct access to secure pages?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

How in Java Web application to restrict direct access to secure pages for not admins roles? For example I have in my application 350-500 URLs and I want to hide 20-30 of them and permit access to them only for admin role. What is best way to solve this problem? What is best practice for this case?

May be I need group necessary URLs by single beginning URI? Or somehow using `web.xml` properties? Or it is enough using saving role of logged user in session and using servlet filter? Problem in that case is I need sort out each secure URL. But there may be many in future...

I think all are facing this problem. Give me the standard and simple solutions of this situation please! Thanks in advance!

I will be grateful for any advices and tips!

Comment: Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncas.html). This is all part of the JavaEE spec, don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below options

- Simply put them in `WEB-INF` where it can't be accessed directly from outside world.

  Read more [What is WEB-INF used for in a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-web-application)
- Apply a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) for the access of the particular path

Yes you can group necessary URLs by single beginning URI that can be filtered by a filter as suggested above.

---

#### It's worth reading [The Java EE 6 Tutorial - Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijrp.html) that explores security concepts and examples

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here..http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-java-servlet-filter-example-using-eclipse-apache-tomcat/

You need to group them somehow in a specific folder.
Than You should create a filter like in the link.. The filter will get anything that in the pattern /admin/(Suppose your pages will be there)

Inside the filter you just need to add the condition..

```
If(!admin) {
    /Redirect to anywhere you want
}
```

You can use something more sufisticated like spring security, This thing will have the logic inside and you just need to set you roles.. Which i think will be better solution, But will take more time if you are not familiar with Spring

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple application it will certainly be overkill, but if allready using SpringFramework, you could have a look at Spring Security. It deals with authentication, with many possibilies, and can have very simple or very sophisticated authorization rules.

[Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org) is also a simpler (but less powerful) alternative.