# Servlet RequestDispatcher is not forwarding

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm learning Java Servlets and JSP.

I have the following code:

`HelloServlet.jsp`

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
       HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8);

        RequestDispatcher aDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("file.jsp");
        aDispatcher.forward(request,response);
   }
}
```

`file.jsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
   pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>First JSP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello!!
    </body>
</html>
```

My `web.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xmlns:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.som/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Hello</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>Hello Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>be.howest.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/urlpattern</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I'm running the file on Tomcat, I get the following error: 
`HTTP Status 404 - /Projectname/file.jsp`

```
type - Status report
message - Projectname/file.jsp
description - The requested resource is not available.
```

What did I do wrong? because I can't find the solution by myself

Comment: Where is `file.jsp` located?

Comment: in the `WEB-INF` folder (it's the normal location in Eclipse)

Comment: Then you'll want to access it through `/WEB-INF/file.jsp`.

Comment: I've putted it under the folder WebContent and now it works. Now it's a stupid question :(

Comment: IS it typo `<url-pattern>/urlpattern</url-pattern>` or the exact url-pattern defined in web.xml. Is it `HelloServlet.jsp` or `HelloServlet.java`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with prefix slash as shown below

```
RequestDispatcher aDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/file.jsp");
```

if jsp file is present directly under webapp folder.

or try

```
RequestDispatcher aDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/file.jsp");
```

if jsp file is under WEB-INF folder.

project structure:

```
WebContent
       |
       |__file.jsp
       |
       |__WEB-INF
              |
              |__file.jsp
              |__web.xml
```

---

Read [What is WEB-INF used for in a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-web-application)

If you want not to access this JSP file directly then put is inside the `WEB-INF` folder that can't accessed publically that is more secure way for restricted resources.

A JSP file placed under WEB-INF can't accessed directly by simply hitting the URL in that case it can be accessed by the application only.

Comment: I've putted it under the folder `WebContent` and now it works. Now it's a stupid question :(