# Not able to acces WEB-INF/JSP folder

Tags: jsp

I created a folder named jsp in WEB-INF & putting all the .jsp files in this folder.
I changed the web.xml

It's giving `HTTP Status 404  /JasperPjt/jsp/Login.jsp Not found`.

Please help me out.

Comment: post ur web.xml file..and also the code that u call login.jsp

Comment: yes..some code would help here

Comment: Move your `jsp` folder outside of the `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: Read it here [how to access jsp under WEB-INF folder](http://www.coderanch.com/t/291403/JSP/java/access-jsp-WEB-INF-folder) and [What is WEB-INF used for in a Java web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-web-application)

Comment: <web-app>
 
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/Login.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 
   </web-app>

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen If i will put outside WEB-INF folder, I am getting the required result. So My query is that, if i will put inside WEB-INF/jsp folder. Then how i will access the jsp page.

Answer (score 5):

The main purpose of putting JSP files in WEB-INF directory is that it will be accessible from the server only, not from client end.(Client will not be able to know the exact URL of file).

If you try to call that file(Files in WEB-INF), server will return HTTP 404.

Just call servlet and then you can call that JSP file like :

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/TargetJspFile.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to access files inside WEB-INF by default. Generally all the jsps and other UI contents should be organized under your application root directory and outside WEB-INF. Probably you can have `MyApp/pages` which cotains your jsps and `MyApp/WEB-INF` separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access .jps files under WEB-INF folder you can access .jsp under Webcontent folder and its the root folder for all UI and other UI related files.

If your seperating them then you need get the conetxt path from that you can access.

the actual structure is:

```
HelloWorld
   |
   ---->src
   |
   ---->wecontent
           |
           ----->WEB-INF
           |
           ----->index.jsp
```

if your seperating

```
HelloWorld
   |
   ---->src
   |
   ---->wecontent
           |
           ----->WEB-INF
           |
           ----->jsps
                  |
                  |---> login.jsp
                  |---> welcome.jsp
```

like this now you need to get like this in jsp

```
<% String path = request.getContextPath(); %>

<a href="<%= path %>/jps/welcome.jsp">Wecome</a>
```

Comment: To place text in code blocks, indent by four spaces, or select the text and click the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a public accessible JSP e.g. as `yourproject/web/login.jsp`
and link your private JSP `yourproject/web/WEB-INF/pages/somesnippet.jsp`
with this code:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/pages/somesnippet.jsp" %>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You cannot directly access files from WEB-INF Folder. You need to either redirect or forward request to it.
2. If you are redirecting or forwarding and then getting this error then,

   `/JasperPjt/WEB-INF/jsp/Login.jsp`

   or I think

   `/WEB-INF/jsp/Login.jsp`  or   `WEB-INF/jsp/Login.jsp`

This should also work.