# can't call jsp in WEB-INF from servlet in default package

Tags: html, jsp, redirect, servlets, forward

in netbeans I have a web app with index.html, getEmployees (servlet) and listEmployees.jsp. I couldn't get the request dispatch to bring me from the second to the third

```
 String destination = "listEmployees.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(destination);
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

, so just testing things out I tried to use `<a href="listEmployees.jsp"> View employees </a>` to bring me to the jsp, that didn't work and neither did using it's location from my file directory. I have commented out all the code except for the forwarding code so this is definitely the only problem.

I think it may be that getEmployees.java is in the  and listEmployees.jsp is in the WEB-INF file folder.. However I have tried using `WEB-INF/listEmployees.jsp` as the destination to the same 404 error

Comment: why you have place jsp file in `WEB-INF` ,it should be in `web` folder?

Comment: Post your code completely and give a screenshot of your project structure

Comment: @swati every time i delete and remake it only goes into the web-inf how do i avert that or accommodate it?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428283/not-able-to-acces-web-inf-jsp-folder) out .