# Java EE - change directory of index.jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, servlets

my structure of .jsp files is: WEB-INF/jsp/....; but i have the index.jsp file in WEB-INF/index.jsp folder. As well i have also another types of files in directory WEB-INF/, i would like to move the index.jsp into the folder like this: WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp. So can i somehow change (in my conf files - not in tomcat settings) that my index page is in another folder? i tried to use this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and many variatons of welcome-file-list but i didnt get working combination.

Answer (score 1):

A JSP file placed under WEB-INF can't accessed directly by simply hitting the URL, it can be accessed only by the application itself.

The `WEB-INF` is more secure way for restricted resources that can't accessed publically.

Read [What is WEB-INF used for in a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-web-application)

---

Redirect, Include or Forward the request form index.jsp to the requested JSP page.

For example :

Create `index.jsp` directly placed under `webcontent` folder and include the `WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp`.

webcontent/index.jsp:

```
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jsp/abc.jsp" %>
```

Comment: im not sure if i understand, but im sorry i wrote bad directory, i have my index.jsp at default directory, its in webapp/index.jsp, but i would like to have it in webapp/WEB-INF/index.jsp, but i can't setup my app to access this index page after starting the application

Comment: Why you want to place it inside the WEB-INF folder?

Comment: oh sry, i'm confused, i just came in... exactly, i would like to move it into WEB-INF/jsp/ folder, it looks more organised if there are all .jsp files together

Comment: Follow the link that I shared you in my post. That might help you.

Comment: i can't find the solution -.-

Answer (score 1):

I dont think  `jsp or any other user-interactive things` should be placed inside the `WEB-INF` as it is not a good practice, it is private and secure part of the application. Only the `.class files,libraries and deployment descripter` resides there. *Alternatively what you can do is create folder named jsp under web-content and place your jsp files there.*

Well even though if you  want to do it try like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

will work if jsp is folder under WEB-INF