# How to include css files in JSP page struts2?

Tags: java, css, jsp, struts2

I'm new to java. And now I'm doing Struts2 project.
I added stylesheet in this path

> /WEB-INF/common/css/style.css

and added bootstrap in this path

> /WEB-INF/common/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css

and included them in JSP file as

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="/WEB-INF/common/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/WEB-INF/common/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Login</title>
```

But css doesn't work when I run the program. What do I need to do in Struts2 to include CSS files?

Comment: remove the /WEB-INF/ from the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your css files out of the WEB-INF directory since it is not public.
Here is a good explanation of what WEB-INF is and how it should be used:
[What is WEB-INF used for in a Java EE web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-web-application)

Answer (score 1):

The CSS file path is depending upon where your JSP files are located. Share your project folder structure.

For example:

```
Application name
   |
   | - WEB_INF
   | - JSP -(If this folder having JSP files)
   | - common/css
   | - JS
```

Then the path of CSS in JSP file is like

```
<link href="../common/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Here single .(dot) represent current directory that is JSP Direcrory(Folder)

and double ..(dot) previous/upper directory that is Application/Main project directory, from this directory its points to  /common/css/style.css

Answer (score 1):

First put all css file and js file put in one JSP page and then that jsp page include in jsp page using  tag...

fine i.e.`<%@include file="header.jsp"%>`

Answer (score 0):

you can't include CSS files in /WEB-INF path, take it in the web root path ,and use /common/css/style.css  to access your page

Comment: Thanks. I changed the directory and it works now. But only the input type button doesn't change although I styled it in the same style sheet

Comment: clean up your browse cache ,and check the file bootstrap.min.js ,the bootstrap should include js file.