# My external css file is not working with jsp page

Tags: jsp

I am trying to add some css in my page but my css is not working.

This is my Welcome file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/welcome-css.css" />
</head>
<body>

<table id="wel-table">
<tr>
<td><a href="<s:url action="/header/headerHome" />">Log In</a>  </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

[this is my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgTj4.png)

Comment: where did you store css file..
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>`

Comment: i have post my directory also please click on given link thankyou

Comment: i did this but its not working

Comment: see me post. you forgot to delete `<link >` after `link css`

Comment: but when i click on my css link it open that file

Comment: i delete that but still not working

Comment: also please take a look at `<a>`.. I don't think you use `action` attribute in here

Comment: i just defind that <a> tag  for my another page thats working fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056030/how-to-include-css-files-in-jsp-page-struts2 can you take a look?

Comment: when i use inline code it works fine                                                      <table border="1px" bordercolor="black">
     <tr>
        <td><a href="<s:url action="header/headerHome" />">Log In</a>  </td>
     </tr>
</table>

Comment: i followed that path brother but i dont know its not working

Comment: is it possible to come online via teamviewer please man i am facing lot of problem i have to finished my project on time

Answer (score 0):

CAn you try it?

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/welcome-css.css" /> 
    </head>
    <body>

    <table id="wel-table">
    <tr>
    <td><a href="<s:url action="/header/headerHome" />">Log In</a>  </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link tag where you include your CSS has an XML closing slash. But your doctype declaration says HTML 4. Either switch your doctype to XHTML, or leave the link tag open as in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylez.css">
```

Also, you might want to get rid of the empty link tag immediately following it.

[Help from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)

Comment: I did this    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/welcome-css.css">