# JSP and other static data files location on Web Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, web-inf

Continue to this question and aswers :
[What is WEB-INF used for in a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-web-application/28157763#28157763)

Further question regarding this issue: Beside making my resource private, is there any special reason I should put my JSP files in WEB-INF? Is there any advantage to put my JSP files outside the WEB-INF? I am using Spring framework if it is related to my question.

Comment: Besides preventing users to execute JSPs without going through the appropriate controller URLs, it makes sure you or your colleagues don't become sloppy and bypass the MVC architecture by linking directly to a view rather than going through a controller. There's no good reason to store them outside of WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **No** -- there is no advantage putting the JSPs outside of the WEB-INF folder, when you use a MVC Framework like Spring-MVC. There are only disadvantages: like someone could directly invoke the JSP and could bypass all you functionally that is implemented on top of the Spring-MVC stack,.

Answer (score 0):

Files within the WEB-INF folder are not directly accessible via an url.
Putting JSP files in the WEB-INF folder make sense if you don't want them to be publicly accessible.

An example of such a case is where you use a MVC framework, where you use JSP as view. The main entry point is an url mapped to a controller, which builds a model and generates the page using JSP. In this case it does not make sense to expose the JSP directly.

Comment: So if I understand correct, it does not make any sense to put all my jsp and htm outside WEB-INF?
What about the function "getResourceAsStream"? I cannot access my resource with it unless they are under WEB-INF?

Comment: If you use a MVC framework, generally not. But there might be an exemption, where an MVC is overkill, such as a simple JSP redirect page. The getResourceAsStream function can be used to directly acces files using their relative or direct path and is not limited to "WEB-INF". You should use it caution, since a bug might expose all of your files.