# where to put XSLT in client webapp

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services, xslt

So I have a functioning eclipse/hibernate/spring webservice with some SOAP services, one of which is `sayHello()` wich returns a string

Calling sayHello with `http://localhost:8080/myWebService/soapServices/sayHello` yields:

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:sayHelloResponse>
      <return>greetings from the web service! time is 2015-09-06T14:39:23.375
      </return>
    </ns2:sayHelloResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've also created a companion webappp (the client) to access the web service.
It needs an XSLT stylesheet to format this response, but where should I put `myStylesheet.xsl` within the project structure of my client webapp?  Under new directory `WEB-INF/stylesheets`?

Comment: Please [refrain from "signing" your posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108452/137826), however good the intentions. You already have a signature, that is your avatar with your name (though currently, you did not set a name, but you can go ahead and [edit it and change it](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1201168) to _Still-learning Steve_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Under new directory WEB-INF/stylesheets?

Yes, you are allowed to do so. The `WEB-INF` directory is hidden from requests by default, but is accessible by code with `getResource` and the like. See [this post on structure and `WEB-INF`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19786283/111575) for some hints on what your options are.

Bottom line: it is up to your gut-feeling to what location you find most convenient. If you want the files to be accessible by browsing, it is probably better *not* to put them inside `WEB-INF`.

As an alternative, you can also compile the resources directly into your Java application as a compiled resource. But often it is easier to use a (configurable) location on disk, which allows post-compilation updates to your file.