# display images on jsp and configure XML file

Tags: image, jsp

Am beginner on Java ee and I try to display images on jsp file by applying a lot of solution but with any result. and I dont know if i need to configure the XML file to make images displaying.

Comment: This question can only be answered if you tell where exactly the images are located in the application.

Comment: Resources under WEB-INF are not publicly accessible. You need to move them up under the web app root. Otherwise they can only be served using a Servlet as a proxy. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19786283/1356423