# How to read a file in tomcat 7 folder using SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, file-io

I have a quick question and wonder if anyone has come across this issue before?

I am trying to read a file from my classpath into a .jsp with spring but I keep getting a 404 even when the url is correct.

eg

/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/file/MyProcess.bpmn

The file is available in the browser from the above url but **not** through the .jsp in the Spring Framework where a 404 (Not Found)is returned.

Has anyone come across this problem before?

Comment: How do you try to open the file in your jsp ? The 404 suggests you tried to forward (which would require a path relative to the servlet context), or redirect (which would require a HTTP url) and you show an absolute path...

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your file out of the WEB-INF directory I think because it won't be accessible from your jsp page.

This link should be useful

[What is WEB-INF used for in a Java EE web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-ee-web-application)