# Ajax Query Doesn't Gets Successful

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have this Ajax query to a html page but it always fails.  The html page is something like this 
only has a `<h1>` tab with some text.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/FindMySize/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/result.html",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#stage').html(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        $('#stage').html("AS");
    }

});
```

Comment: can you specify the `dataType` and the `type`

Comment: What error does it show in console?

Comment: User .load("url") very simple no need of extra parameters

Comment: you are missing: `type:'get'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your javascript is OK.**

The problem is your Java structure, the file `result.html` here has not relationship with `jsp`. You shouldn't put it inside WEB-INF. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-ee-web-application?answertab=active#tab-top) SO answer for more clear understanding.

> The  WEB-INF node is not part of the public document tree of the application. No file contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served directly to a client by the container

**Solution:** Move your html to **public folder** (where you store your javascript, css, img,..)

Answer (score 0):

add button click event before ajax call

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:8080/FindMySize/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/result.html",
   success: function(data) {
     $('#stage').html(data);
   },
   error: function(data) {
     $('#stage').html("AS");
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: how `button click event before ajax call` will solve the issue

Comment: i think so b'coz we need some event before ajax call.please check it .may be helpfull for you

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your code

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
type: "POST",
```

Also decide what you use GET or POST and write or `type: "POST"` or `type: "GET"`

> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Also put your code in a function and call it when click button for example

```
<button onclick="f();return false;">

function f() { /*your js code here*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one,     
   $.ajax
        ({
            url: "../FindMySize/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/result.html",
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            async: false,    
            data: {},
            success: function(data) {
                alert("success");//to check whether it was working or not
                $('#stage').html(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
    alert("error");
                $('#stage').html("AS");
            }

    });
```