# Web-Apps - Method of accessing files in the webapp folder?

Tags: url, servlets, navigation, tomcat7

I am working on a project for my grad school. And I am using Servlets for that. Now, I need to read a HTML file (that is located on the server's webapp directory itself) from my servlet.

For example, the sample code is:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("..\\..\\WebContent\\index.html"));

    int ch;

    while((ch = fr.read()) != -1)
    {
        sb.append((char)ch);
    }

    pw.print(new String(sb));
    fr.close();
    }catch(Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code returns an exception: `FileNotFoundException` even though the `index.html` file exists. What is the remedy for this? Is there a workaround?

And BTW, I am using the Eclipse JEE Mars IDE along with Tomcat 7 Web Server

Comment: Try placing index.html in the WEB-INF folder and then access it directly without giving any other path.

Comment: Check this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-ee-web-application