# How does jHipster serve static files but not from META-INF/** and WEB-INF/**?

Tags: jhipster

I noticed that applications generated by *jHipster* serve almost all file content available from the WAR artifact. For example, if there is a file `README.MD` next to `index.html`, it can be accessed via *http://localhost:8080/README.MD*.

The only files that aren't served are those files within the `META-INF/` and `WEB-INF/` directories.

Where does a *jHipster* application's source code configure to serve arbitrary files but not files from `META-INF/**` and `META-INF/**`?

Comment: For WEB-INF this is specified by Servlet Spec http://stackoverflow.com/a/19786283/93960

Comment: So it's in Tomcat, not JHipster

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, good hint, though [Servlet 3.0 adds a twist to it, serving *some* content from WEB-INF](https://alexismp.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/web-inflib-jarmeta-infresources/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no configuration at all, it's part of the Servlet specification: both of those directories are secured by the servlet container, without doing anything specific.

You might be confused because many people store their files in `WEB-INF`, for example `WEB-INF/jsp/` for the JSP files. People do this to protect those files from being accessed directly, and have a Controller (like a Spring MVC controller or Struts controller) that redirects to those pages once it has processed the request.

JHipster works differently, as it only has static pages that do REST requests to the back-end, so it's a different architecture.

Comment: It's serving what is inside `src/main/webapp` in your project, which is the standard Maven directory for this.

Comment: @JulienDubios, thanks! I found the relevant code in `WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry)` in conjunction with the `@ConfigurationProperties` properties sources `ResourceProperties` and `WebMvcProperties`. [It is also mentioned in the Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content), albeit subtly ("*Spring Boot will serve static content [...] from the root of the ServletContext.*").