# Prevent Tomcat from serializing session when running locally from IntelliJ IDE

Tags: session, tomcat, serialization, intellij-idea, tomcat8

I am successfully running [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) 8.5.16 locally from [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2017.2 Ultimate edition via the bundled *Tomcat and TomEE Integration* plugin.

When stopping the Tomcat server, I get errors about some objects in my session not being serializable. I do not care to serialize the sessions, as I expect to start fresh user sessions in the case of a server-bounce or such event.

➠ How to stop Tomcat from serializing sessions when invoked from IntelliJ?

Comment: Are you sure it's specific to IntelliJ IDEA? Do you mean that you don't get these messages if you start/stop Tomcat outside of IntelliJ IDEA and deploy your app manually?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I've not gotten that far yet, have not run my app independently without IntelliJ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Tomcat feature

This is a pure tomcat feature, independent of how you start it. From the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts):

> Disable Session Persistence
>
> As documented above, every web application by default has standard
>   manager implementation configured, and it performs session persistence
>   across restarts. To disable this persistence feature, create a Context
>   configuration file for your web application and add the following
>   element there:
>
> `<Manager pathname="" />`

## Example of disabling session persistence

For example, in the [`META-INF`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19786142/642706) folder of your web app, add a [`context.xml`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) file as shown below.

```xml
<!-- 'context.xml' file in 'META-INF' folder of your web app -->
<Context>
    <Manager pathname="" />
</Context>
```

You should be able to add this into your project in your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). You may need to explicitly add the `META-INF` folder if one is not already configured within your project. Here is a screen shot in [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IntelliJ_IDEA) 2017 after adding the folder and file.

[image: screen shot of IntelliJ project structure where a 'META-INF' folder has been added to the project so as to contain a 'context.xml' file]