# Add web.xml in Spring Maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

In a Spring 'Maven' project, where to place web.xml file?

I am creating a spring mvc project and not sure about where to put web.xml in the project.

Comment: The location of `web.xml` is `WEB-INF`, and this doesn't change because you are using Spring.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, but I don't have WEB-INF directory in Spring Tool Suite solution

Comment: If you don't even know where your `web.xml` file is, then maybe the framework is taking care of it for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-ee-web-application

Answer (score 5):

This is an example of a structure of Spring project with maven

```
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── com
│       │       └── hellokoding
│       │           └── hello
│       │               └── web
│       │                   └── YourClass.java
│       ├── resources
│       │   ├── application.properties
│       │   └── logback.xml
│       └── webapp
│           ├── resources
│           │   ├── css
│           │   │   └── bootstrap.min.css
│           │   ├── images
│           │   └── js
│           │       └── bootstrap.min.js
│           └── WEB-INF
│               ├── views
│               │   └── hello.jsp
|               ├── appconfig-mvc.xml
│               ├── appconfig-root.xml 
│               └── web.xml 
└── pom.xml
```

From [here](https://hellokoding.com/spring-mvc-4-hello-world-example-with-xml-configuration-maven-and-jsp/)

Comment: Unless you really typed this out yourself, you should definitely add a source for this information.

Answer (score 1):

it's WEB-INF/web.xml  Check out the below link ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html
No matter how your archetype structures the project, the final build always follow the specifications.
I know the frameworks like spring hides all the specification details and nowadays newbies don't pay attention to all such details. Well knowing specifications and how the frameworks are constructed over these specifications adds value to your software development skills.

Answer (score 0):

web.xml file is always inside WEB-INF folder, by default Maven is expecting it in there and its the first location that is being searched for a web.xml file.