# Spring Boot cant detect html files (Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm using Spring Boot and running the webapp on the embedded Tomcat server

I got this error: "o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : "Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [static/WEB-INF/views/loginPage.html]""

Here's my controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingsController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String greetingText() {
        return "loginPage";
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
server.address=0.0.0.0
server.port=8080
    
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /static/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

Project structure:

[image]

- webapp folder is empty

I'm confident that I have most necessary dependencies installed (Jasper, Spring Boot, Thymeleaf,..). I have done a good amount of searching on my own

Please do note that I have also tried moving the WEB-INF folder to the webapp and changing the view prefix accordingly, however, it did not come to fruition

Comment: Why did you put it in sub directory WEB-INF? It should be in resources/templates

Comment: follow the standard way, put views in  resources/templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Don't store your files in the WEB-INF directory.

Note the part in bold below.

From the Servlet 2.4 Spec: The WEB-INF node is not part of the public document tree of the application. **No file contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served directly to a client by the container.**

This is an excerpt from: [What is WEB-INF used for in a Java EE web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-ee-web-application)